# I try to cunnecte mongoDB but there is a mongo server error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, server

```
**MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.**
    at Connection.onMessage (E:\project\milestone11-Backend-and-DataBase-integrate\module-70-Backend-Database-Milestone-Assignment\inventory-management-a11-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:203:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (E:\project\milestone11-Backend-and-DataBase-integrate\module-70-Backend-Database-Milestone-Assignment\inventory-management-a11-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at processIncomingData (E:\project\milestone11-Backend-and-DataBase-integrate\module-70-Backend-Database-Milestone-Assignment\inventory-management-a11-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (E:\project\milestone11-Backend-and-DataBase-integrate\module-70-Backend-Database-Milestone-Assignment\inventory-management-a11-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your user and password is correct in the connection string you have copied from the MongoDB.